# swift2: Extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: swift2, nsurlconnection, nserror

xCode: Extra argument 'error' in call.

**This the error code**

```
var responseError: NSError?
var response: NSURLResponse?

let urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &responseError)
```

how can help me to fix this error. Thank you.
I'm find more information but it error is difficult to fix.

Comment: in swift2 remove error parameter and use do / try / catch pattern

Comment: Sorry, could you please make the example for me?

Comment: see Pradeep's answer and take in account that the function throws

Comment: Look at the *Related* column, there are many many many similar questions and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the error parameter then it still gives the error, please find the below.

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and error is not
>   handled.

So it is recommended that you can use the new `NSURLSession` and as @Pradeep had mentioned that it is deprecated in iOS 9.

Please find the below sample how to use the `NSURLSession`.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: YOUR_URL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        print(data)
        print(response)
        print(error)
    })
    task.resume()
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing the error parameter.

```
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
```

Buts its recommended to use `NSURLSession's dataTaskWithRequest` since the above call is deprecated in iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

see Pradeep's answer. if you still want to use it ..

```
do {
    let urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
} catch {
    // in case the function throws an error
}

// or 

let urlData = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
```

Comment: I have make the do try catch but it can not fix this.

Comment: ?? what error do you have now? i see your own 'answer', there is missing do part there (may be just typo?)